# Running php bin/magento commands returns nothing on 2.2.7 CLI php 7.0.22

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.2, mamp

I'm having some problems running the `php bin/magento` commands using PHP 7.0.22 on MAMP Pro, Mac, Magento 2.2.7

The commands was working about 2 hours ago when all of a sudden stopped working whereby my terminal would just seem to return nothing after running the command.

I have tried switching PHP versions to 7.1.12 however this isn't going to cause the problem, if anything I have better luck their but get an error relating to Encrypter.

I get the following errors when trying to run the Magento commands in my terminal and I'm not sure why:

```
[13-Feb-2019 16:38:19 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.22/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/intl.so' - dlopen(/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.22/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/intl.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
[13-Feb-2019 16:38:25 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class Zend_Mail_Message, because the name is already in use in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MYSITE/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Mail/Message.php on line 39
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

Changing to PHP 7.1 fixes the intl error, but I then get: Notice: Undefined variable: cipher in `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MYSITE/vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php on line 397` - I have the `mcrypt.so` module installed and active

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are missing php extension `intl`, after switch php 7.1 please make sure all the magento system required php extensions are installed.

You can find the **Magento2.2.X** needed php extension lists from [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html#php)

I hope it helps.

Comment: Any ideas on the Zend error? And in terms of `intl` I was able to setup the project and have been developing on it some time without that file, this is weird behaviour that it's causing this error, any other suggestions here?

Comment: Changing to PHP 7.1 fixes the `intl` error, but I then get: `Notice: Undefined variable: cipher in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MYSITE/vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php on line 397` - I have the mcrypt.so module installed and active